# Mysql Source Distribution Version

Tags: mysql, centos

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html), there are only two MySQL version

1. Community
2. Enterprise

However the version that I installed from my CentOS repo, It is "Source Distribution"

```
mysql> show variables like '%version%';
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| version                 | 5.1.73              |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64              |
| version_compile_os      | redhat-linux-gnu    |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I get that as I installed it via repo, it is stating "Source Distribution", but where does it fall in legal terms ?

Comment: After googling, found out it is just like community version, the only difference is, it is compiled and maintained by repo.

Comment: Post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for trouble guys. I found my answer. 
After googling, found out it is just like community version, the only difference is, it is compiled and maintained by repo.